# How to grant permissions on a table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, functions

Am I doing it right...?

I have a function that returns money...

```
CREATE FUNCTION functionName( @a_principal money, @a_from_date
  datetime, @a_to_date datetime, @a_rate float )  RETURNS money AS BEGIN

  DECLARE @v_dint money   set @v_dint = computation_here
     set @v_dint = round(@v_dint, 2)

  RETURN @v_dint    
END 
GO 
Grant execute on functionName to another_user 
Go
```

Im just wondering if this is possible to be converted to iTVF?

I've tried doing this but I got an error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION functionName ( @a_principal money, @a_from_date
  datetime, @a_to_date datetime, @a_rate float )  
RETURNS TABLE AS 
RETURN SELECT returnMoney = computation_here  
GO  
Grant execute on functionName to another_user  Go
```

**ERROR:**

> Msg 4606, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
>       Granted or revoked privilege EXECUTE is not compatible with object.

This function is used like this:

```
update table_name set interest = functionName(col1,col2...) where...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you are now returning a table, the GRANT statement needs to be GRANT SELECT, rather than GRANT EXECUTE.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Scalar functions require `EXECUTE` permissions, however when you've converted to a Table Valued Function the permissions required change to `SELECT`.

You must now `GRANT SELECT ON functionName TO another_user;`

From [BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905178(v=sql.80).aspx):

> Users other than the owner must be granted EXECUTE permission on a function (if the function is scalar-valued) before they can use it in a Transact-SQL statement. **If the function is table-valued, the user must have SELECT permissions on the function before referencing it.**

Comment: And per RDFozz's comment on another answer, if the user name has special characters (like a backslash, as in DOMAINNAME\username) then you need to put the username in square brackets, viz: `grant select on functionName to [DOMAINNAME\username];`

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `GRANT SELECT ON functionName TO [another_user]` - with brackets.

Comment: The brackets are optional unless the username includes a special character. Since backslash is a special character, and is often going to be part of the user name for users w/ Windows authentication logins, it's probably safest to be in the habit of using the brackets.

Answer (score -3):

I tried to use:

```
GRANT SELECT ON functionName TO another_user
```

But it didn't work, then, I used `EXECUTE` instead of `SELECT`, and it works now

Comment: I'm curious as to how you managed this, as attempting to `grant execute` on a SQL function will always throw an error.

Comment: It was probably not a table-valued function, that's why it worked.

Comment: The was helpful, mine was an `aggregate` function